# Overload the opposite of the negation operator?

Tags: c++, c++11

Overloading the negation operator is simple:

```
bool MyClass::operator!() const
{
    //return whatever comparison needs to be done
}
```

Then I can write:

```
MyClass a;
if(!a)
{
    //Do something
}
```

But I want to be able to write:

```
if(a)
{
    //Do something
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Overload the `bool` conversion operator; it works for both cases.

Comment: `operator bool() const {...}`

Comment: @Shawn ah great, didn't know about that, thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in an if-statement will be converted to bool. So, what you need to do is make your class convertible to bool. This can be achieved by defining a conversion operator:

```
struct MyClass {
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Once you've done this, you don't need an overload for `operator!` anymore because the bool can be negated after conversion.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!